# Java: Null-Pointer Exception- replacing values in html with database values in Server

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, database, server

I am completing a school project- After the user submits the form, an object is to be created, and it is added to MySQL database. Then a "list" is to be shown of the title sorted by the timestamp. It also must have a thumbnail picture and delete button. I am trying to replace the input text values in the html page, with values from the database in the form of an array. The ApplicationDao is communicating with the database and is suppose to place those values in the array.

I have been following the tutorial https://www.linkedin.com/learning/java-ee-servlets-and-javaserver-pages-jsp/search-building-a-servlet-response?autoplay=true&resume=false&u=2199673
but the values are not being replaced and I am getting the following exception:
***Updated:After changing the Log log= new textLog to log= new TextLog, I am now recieving the below error! Thanks for all your help!

** also I know some code is repeated, it is suppose to be on one page I was just trying to figure out a solution!

```
   Jun. 16, 2022 1:41:41 P.M. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.algonquin.loggy.servlets.deleteServlet] in context with path [/Loggy-Lab3] threw exception
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:459)
    at com.algonquin.loggy.servlets.deleteServlet.getHTMLString(deleteServlet.java:65)
    at com.algonquin.loggy.servlets.deleteServlet.doGet(deleteServlet.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)



Here is my code:

public  class Log {
    private String uuid;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private String createTimestamp;
    
  
    
    
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
       public String getUUID() {
            return uuid;
        }

        public void setUUID(String uuid) {  
            this.uuid = uuid;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }

        public void setContent(String content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

        public String getCreateTimestamp() {
            return createTimestamp;
        }

        public void setCreateTimestamp(String createTimestamp) {
            this.createTimestamp=createTimestamp;
            
        }
}


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.algonquin.loggy.beans.Log;
import com.algonquin.loggy.beans.TextLog;
import com.algonquin.loggy.dao.ApplicationDao;
import com.algonquin.loggy.dao.DBConnection;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LogsServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/LogsServlet" )
public class LogsServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public LogsServlet() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String htmlResponse = "<html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\"><title>Loggy Servlet Form</title></head>"
                + "<body><form id=\"logForm\" action=\"LogsServlet\" method=\"post\" >\n"
                + "        <h3>Create A New Log!</h3>\n"
                + "       \n"
                + "        <label id=\"logTitleLabel\" for=\"title\">Title :</label>\n"
                + "        <br>\n"
                + "        <input type=\"text\" id=\"logTitle\" name=\"title\" maxLength=\"60\">\n"
                + "        <br>\n"
                
                + "        <label id=\"logContentLabel\" for=\"content\">Content :</label>\n"
                + "        <br>\n"
                + "        <input type=\"text\" id=\"logContent\" name=\"content\">\n"
                + "        <br>\n"
                + "        <button type=\"submit\" id=\"submitLog\">Submit Log</button>\n"
                + "        \n"
                + "        </form></body></html>";;
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.write(htmlResponse);
    }


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException{
    
    String title = request.getParameter("title");
    String content = request.getParameter("content");
    String output;
    String uuid =UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String createTimestamp=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new java.util.Date());
    
    Log log= new TextLog();
    //ApplicationDao dao = new ApplicationDao();
    //List<Log> logs= dao.listLogs();
    

    
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    try {
        
        log.setTitle(title);
        log.setContent(content);
        log.setCreateTimestamp(createTimestamp);
        log.setUUID(uuid);
        
        //logsList.add(log);
        
        output="<html><body><h3>Log successfully created</h3></body></html>";
        writer.write(output);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            output="<html><body><h3>Log could not be created</h3></body></html>";
            writer.write(output);
        }
    
            

    String indexForm = "<html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\"><title>Loggy Servlet Form</title></head>"
            + "<body><form id=\"logForm\" action=\"LogsServlet\" method=\"post\" >\n"
            + "        <h3>Create A New Log!</h3>\n"
            + "       \n"
            + "        <label id=\"logTitleLabel\" for=\"title\">Title :</label>\n"
            + "        <br>\n"
            + "        <input type=\"text\" id=\"logTitle\" name=\"title\" maxLength=\"60\">\n"
            + "        <br>\n"
        
            + "        <label id=\"logContentLabel\" for=\"content\">Content :</label>\n"
            + "        <br>\n"
            + "        <input type=\"text\" id=\"logContent\" name=\"content\">\n"
            + "        <br>\n"
            + "        <button type=\"submit\" id=\"submitLog\">Submit Log</button>\n"
            + "        \n"
            + "        </form></body></html>";
    
    writer.write(indexForm);
    
    String insertQuery ="INSERT INTO `logs`(`uuid`, `title`, `content`, `createTimestamp`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    Connection connection =DBConnection.getConnectionToDatabase();
    
    
    java.sql.PreparedStatement statement;
    try {
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
        statement.setString(1,log.getUUID());
        statement.setString(2,log.getTitle());
        statement.setString(3,log.getContent());
        statement.setString(4,log.getCreateTimestamp());
        
        statement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    String list ="<div class=\"logContainer\">\n"
            + "        <form>\n"
            + "        \n"
            + "        <div class=\"logContainerItem\">\n"
            + "        <img src=\"images/journal1.png\" height=\"60px\" width=\"60px\">\n"
            + "        <input type=\"text\" name=\"log\" value=\"{0}\">\n"
            + "        <button>Delete Log</button>\n"
            + "        </div>\n"
            + "        \n"
            + "         <div class=\"logContainerItem\">\n"
            + "        <img src=\"images/journal1.png\" height=\"60px\" width=\"60px\">\n"
            + "        <input type=\"text\" name=\"log\" value=\"{1}\">\n"
            + "        <button>Delete Log</button>\n"
            + "        </div>\n"
            + "        \n"
            + "         <div class=\"logContainerItem\">\n"
            + "        <img src=\"images/journal1.png\" height=\"60px\" width=\"60px\">\n"
            + "        <input type=\"text\" name=\"log\" value=\"{2}\">\n"
            + "        <button>Delete Log</button>\n"
            + "        </div>\n"
            + "        \n"
            + "         <div class=\"logContainerItem\">\n"
            + "        <img src=\"images/journal1.png\" height=\"60px\" width=\"60px\">\n"
            + "        <input type=\"text\" name=\"log\" value=\"{3}\">\n"
            + "        <button>Delete Log</button>\n"
            + "        </div>\n"
            + "        \n"
            + "        </form>\n"
            + "        \n"
            + "        \n"
            + "        \n"
            + "        </div>\n"
            + "";
    
    writer.write(list);
    
    
    
    
    //String page = getHTMLString(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/html/ListLogs.html"), logs);
    //response.getWriter().write(page);

}

//public String getHTMLString(String filePath, List<Log> logs) throws IOException{
//  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
//  String line="";
//  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
//  while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
//      buffer.append(line);
//  }
    
//  reader.close();
//  String page = buffer.toString();
    
//  page = MessageFormat.format(page,logs.get(0).getTitle(),
            //logs.get(1).getTitle(),logs.get(2).getTitle(),0);
    
    //return page;
    
    
//}




}



import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.algonquin.loggy.beans.Log;
import com.algonquin.loggy.beans.TextLog;
import com.algonquin.loggy.services.ApplicationService;

public class ApplicationDao implements ApplicationService {


        @SuppressWarnings("null")
        public List<Log> listLogs() {
                
            Log log=null;
            List<Log> logs = new ArrayList<>();
            
            
            try{
                Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnectionToDatabase();
                
                String sql = "SELECT title FROM `logs` ORDER BY createTimestamp";
                
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                
                ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                
                while(set.next()){
                    
                    log = new Log();
                    log.setTitle(set.getString("title"));
                    log.setContent(set.getString("content"));
                    log.setCreateTimestamp(set.getString("createTimestamp"));
                    log.setUUID(set.getString("UUID"));
                    
            
                    logs.add(log);
                    
                }

            }
            catch(SQLException exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return logs;

            }
    }


package com.algonquin.loggy.servlets;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.algonquin.loggy.beans.Log;
import com.algonquin.loggy.dao.ApplicationDao;




@WebServlet("/deleteServlet")
public class deleteServlet extends HttpServlet{
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    
        
        
        
        //call DAO layer and get all products for search criteria
        ApplicationDao dao = new ApplicationDao();
        List<Log> logs = dao.listLogs();
        
        //write the products data back to the client browser
        String page = getHTMLString(req.getServletContext().getRealPath("/ListLogs.html"), logs);
        resp.getWriter().write(page);
        
        
    }
    
    /**
     * this methods reads the HTML template as a String, replaces placeholders
     * with the values and returns the entire page as a String
     * @param filePath
     * @param products
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    
    public String getHTMLString(String filePath, List<Log> logs) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String line="";
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        
        reader.close();
        String page = buffer.toString();
        
        page = MessageFormat.format(page, logs.get(0).getTitle(),
                logs.get(1).getTitle(),logs.get(2).getTitle(),logs.get(3).getTitle());
        
        return page;
        
        
    }
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>List Of Submitted Logs</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="logContainer">
        <form method="get" action="deleteServlet">
        
        <div class="logContainerItem">
        <img src="images/journal1.png" height="60px" width="60px">
        <input type="text" name="log" value="{0}">
        <button>Delete Log</button>
        </div>
        
         <div class="logContainerItem">
        <img src="images/journal1.png" height="60px" width="60px">
        <input type="text" name="log" value="{1}">
        <button>Delete Log</button>
        </div>
        
         <div class="logContainerItem">
        <img src="images/journal1.png" height="60px" width="60px">
        <input type="text" name="log" value="{2}">
        <button>Delete Log</button>
        </div>
        
         <div class="logContainerItem">
        <img src="images/journal1.png" height="60px" width="60px">
        <input type="text" name="log" value="{3}">
        <button>Delete Log</button>
        </div>
        
        </form>
        
        
        
        </div>

</body>
</html>


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnection {

    // Database Schema
    // CREATE DATABASE loggy DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
    // CREATE TABLE logs (uuid CHAR(40) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, title CHAR(128),
    // content TEXT, createTimestamp Date);

     private static final String dbUser = "user";
        private static final String dbPassword = "password";
        private static Connection connection = null;
        

        public static Connection getConnectionToDatabase() {
            

            try {

                // load the driver class
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");

                // get hold of the DriverManager
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/loggy",dbUser,dbPassword);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            if (connection != null) {
                System.out.println("Connection made to DB!");
            }
            return connection;
            
        }
        

          
    }
```

Thankyou in advance, and hope my question makes sense!

Comment: What is on the line (and around) `com.algonquin.loggy.dao.ApplicationDao.listLogs(ApplicationDao.java:37)`?

Comment: `Log log=null;`  then you commented out `Log log = new TextLog();` so `log.setTitle(set.getString("title"));` crashes.

Comment: It's is log.setTitle(set.getString("title"));

Comment: When I uncomment the new text log I get a duplicate locable variable log error. How would I fix this? I tried placing the log=null  within the while block but it still does the same thing

Comment: Write `log = new TextLog();` without the leading `Log `.

Comment: I did so and now the exception has changed - going to update question!

Comment: Okay. Did you try to interpret the exception? What the problem it describes and where in your code the problem is?

Comment: It looks to me that your SQL query, i.e. `SELECT title FROM logs ORDER BY createTimestamp` (in method `listLogs()` of class `ApplicationDao`) is not returning any data. Hence you are calling method `getHTMLString` with an empty list so when you call `logs.get(0)` you are getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because, as the error message says, there is no element at index 0 (zero) when there are no elements in the `List`. I suggest that you check whether the query returns any results (or not).

Comment: When I query on phpMyAdmin I get 4 results( which is all of them), I'm not sure how to check within the program though.. sorry this is my first time with dynamic web, and I can't seem to just try and system print it.. any suggestion on how to verify it?